# Unable to display join table in a view on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am pretty new to ror and have tried a couple other similar posts but am still getting an error. 
I have this models:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :user
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
   has_many :ticket_categories
   has_many :categories, through: :ticket_categories
end

class TicketCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ticket
   belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ticket_categories
   has_many :tickets, through: :ticket_categories
end
```

In the Ticket index controller I have:

```
def index
    @tickets = Ticket.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    @category = Category.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

In the View I have:

```
<tbody>
  <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <tr>
     <td><%= ticket.id %></td>
     <td><%= ticket.title %></td>
     <td><%= ticket.description %></td>
     <td><%= ticket.created_at%></td>
    <td>
    <ul>
      <% if @ticket.categories.any? %>
      <%= @ticket.categories %>
        <li><%= category.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </td>
```

In view, I got this error undefined method `categories' for nil:NilClass
Did i do something wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping `@tickets` with the variable `ticket`. So you should call `categories` method on `ticket` and not `@ticket`(which is `nil`).

```
<% if ticket.categories.any? %>
  <% ticket.categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= category.name %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have added the code to loop through `categories` and display each `category`'s name.

Comment: @bendee74, Updated my answer. Does this help?

Comment: i test your code it display like this : 

Software
Application
[#<Category id: 1, name: "Software", created_at: "2016-08-15 12:35:55", updated_at: "2016-08-15 12:35:55">, #<Category id: 3, name: "Application", created_at: "2016-08-15 12:36:52", updated_at: "2016-08-15 12:36:52">]

Comment: my working code is like this <% if ticket.categories.any? %>
  <% render ticket.categories%>
  <% end %>
then under view categories folder add code <%= category.name %> to file _category.html.erb

Comment: @bendee74 Great! Thats neat actually.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<ul>
  <% if ticket.categories.any? %>
    <%= ticket.categories %>
    <li><%= category.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tq.. Opps.. new error -  undefined local variable or method `category' for #<#<Class:0x8959c20>:0xb1e14b0>.. where do i define that category.name variable..??